# ASP.NET MVC: Updating model from within model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

In a controller, I do the following:

```
DBContext DB = new DBContext();
var u = DB.Users.Find(1);
u.firstname = "blah";
UpdateModel(u);
DB.SaveChanges();
```

I want to do the same from within a model...

```
namespace Project.Models
{
  public class User
  {
    public void resetPassword()
    {
      // Generate new password, etc.
      this.password = "blah";
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea how I go about doing this? It seems `UpdateModel()` is only available from within controllers.

I'm using EntityFramework Code-First CTP5.

Comment: What are you achieving using UpdateModel() here that would be related to the DB?

Answer (score 1):

I think UpTheCreek is correct but it probably needs some explanation so I'll try to expand on his/her answer. The first step would be to use the [repository pattern](https://web.archive.org/web/20110503184234/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/08/the-repository-pattern.aspx). You can find many examples of this pattern in MVC with a google search - [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-model-classes-with-linq-to-sql-cs) is a particularly gentle introduction (about 3/4's down the page).

The walkthrough goes on to mention dependency injection, and that's something that's also worth looking in to. I tend to favor [Ninject](http://ninject.org/) myself, however there are [other](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx) dependency injection containers available.

Comment: Yes, this is a better answer than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

Putting data access concerns in your model is not a good idea.

Update: Yes, you'd usually have a data access layer for this. As Andy says, the currently fashionable way to do this is using a repository. As a rule, you don't want anything in your model that is not core business logic.

Comment: How about from a non-controller class, where I get the same issue? It's obviously wrong to call a function in one controller from another controller, so logically I'd encapsulate this into a library class..?